# Infinit loop when constructing linked list

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:
        int data;
        Node *next;
};
int main()
{
    Node *head=NULL;
    Node *temp;
    Node *nodeToAdd;
    int ch,val,pos,flag=1;
    while(flag){
        cout<<"\n1.Add at End  2.Add at head  3.Traverse  4.Insert between Nodes  9.EXIT\n";
        cin>>ch;
        switch(ch){
            case 1:
                nodeToAdd=new Node();
                cout<<"Enter Value - ";
                cin>>val;
                nodeToAdd->data=val;
                if(head==NULL){
                    head=nodeToAdd;
                }
                else{
                    temp=head;
                    while(temp->next!=NULL){
                        temp=temp->next;
                    }
                    temp->next=nodeToAdd;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                nodeToAdd=new Node();
                cout<<"Enter Value - ";
                cin>>val;
                nodeToAdd->data=val;
                if(head==NULL){
                    head=nodeToAdd;
                }
                else{
                    nodeToAdd->next=head;
                    head=nodeToAdd;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if(head==NULL){
                    cout<<"List is Empty";
                    return 0;
                }
                else{
                    temp=head;
                    while(temp!=NULL){
                        cout<<temp->data<<"->";
                        temp=temp->next;
                    }
                }
                cout<<"NULL";
                break;
            case 4:
                nodeToAdd=new Node();
                cout<<"Enter Value - ";
                cin>>val;
                cout<<"Enter Position - ";
                cin>>pos;
                nodeToAdd->data=val;
                if(head==NULL){
                    cout<<"List Is Empty";
                    return 0;
                }
                else{
                    temp=head;
                    int i=1;

                    while(i<pos){
                        i++;
                        temp=temp->next;
                    }
                    temp->next=nodeToAdd;
                    nodeToAdd->next=temp->next;
                }
                break;
            case 9:
                flag=0;
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

in case 1 or 2 nodes are added successfully and are traversed after it without any error but after running case 4 node is added without any error but when i try to traverse the list loop runs infinitely i can't understand my mistake. Please tell me my mistake in case 4 when inserting node between two nodes.

Comment: `temp->next = nodeToAdd; nodeToAdd->next=temp->next;` think carefully about the order of those two statements. You change `temp->next`. Then you set `nodeToAdd->next` to the _new value_ of `temp->next`, i.e. `nodeToAdd` itself.

Comment: You don't initialize `next` in most cases, which may be a source of infinite loop.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're making a C-style linked list. It would be great if C++ was actually used to teach data structures in a class that claims to use C++.

Comment: This is something you should be able to spot easily if you stepped through the code in a debugger looking at the variables at each step. And I mean stepping 1 line at a time not just executing the code in the debugger actively debugging the code.

Answer (score -2):

Hi there thanks everyone for your responses. Now i got correct answer to my question. Now the correct code is i hope this code will be helpful to other developers also

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:
        int data;
        Node *next;
};
int main()
{
    Node *head=NULL;
    Node *temp;
    Node *nodeToAdd;
    int ch,val,pos,flag=1;
    while(flag){
        cout<<"\n1.Add at End  2.Add at head  3.Traverse  4.Insert between Nodes  9.EXIT\n";
        cin>>ch;
        switch(ch){
            case 1:
                nodeToAdd=new Node();
                cout<<"Enter Value - ";
                cin>>val;
                nodeToAdd->data=val;
                if(head==NULL){
                    head=nodeToAdd;
                }
                else{
                    temp=head;
                    while(temp->next!=NULL){
                        temp=temp->next;
                    }
                    temp->next=nodeToAdd;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                nodeToAdd=new Node();
                cout<<"Enter Value - ";
                cin>>val;
                nodeToAdd->data=val;
                if(head==NULL){
                    head=nodeToAdd;
                }
                else{
                    nodeToAdd->next=head;
                    head=nodeToAdd;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if(head==NULL){
                    cout<<"List is Empty";
                    return 0;
                }
                else{
                    temp=head;
                    while(temp!=NULL){
                        cout<<temp->data<<"->";
                        temp=temp->next;
                    }
                }
                cout<<"NULL";
                break;
            case 4:
                nodeToAdd=new Node();
                cout<<"Enter Value - ";
                cin>>val;
                cout<<"Enter Position - ";
                cin>>pos;
                nodeToAdd->data=val;
                if(head==NULL){
                    cout<<"List Is Empty";
                    return 0;
                }
                else{
                    temp=head;
                    int i=0;

                    while(i<pos-1){
                        temp=temp->next;
                        i++;
                    }
                    nodeToAdd->next=temp->next;
                    temp->next=nodeToAdd;
                }
                break;
            case 9:
                flag=0;
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did not downvote however I believe you should explain the changes made in the code for future readers.